# SVG spinner does not rotate on Origin

Tags: html, css, animation, svg

I am using an `img` tag wrapped by a `div` to display a svg spinner. The `div` has a rotate animation on it. Do you know why its not spinning on the origin and why are the inline-spinners overlapping?

I cannot use SVG animationTransform because IE does not support it. Since its a simple spinner, I was hoping to rotate just the div and get the loading effect.

Here's the plunkr demo:

https://plnkr.co/edit/jiuI4rlETsNHN1yLbG2k?p=preview

```
<div class="spinner">
    <img src="spinner.svg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="spinner">
    <img src="spinner.svg" alt="">
  </div>

  <h4>Inline Spinners</h4>
  <div class="spinner-inline">
    <img src="spinner.svg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="spinner-inline">
    <img src="spinner.svg" alt="">
  </div>
```

/* Styles go here */

```
body{
  background: #444;
  color: white;
}

.spinner{
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

.spinner-inline{
  display: inline-block;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

@keyframes spin{
  0% {transform: rotate(0deg);}
  100% {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
```

Update:

```
.spinner *{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}


.spinner-inline *{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Adding above CSS for child elements helped a little but the inline spinners still dont spin on origin.

Comment: you can use [fakeSmile](https://leunen.me/fakesmile/) to enable animateTransform in IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your inline-spinners have an offset in the transform origin is because the default `line-height` (`28px`) takes over your height, so resetting that you solve the origin problem:

```
.spinner-inline{
  display: inline-block;
  height: 10px;
  line-height:0;/*****/
  width: 10px;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/mW7BamvPST89ufqNyE8N?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

I looked at your plunkr, although I don't believe I can answer the origin question, the inline spinners is an easy fix.

You have the `width` and `height` set to `20px` (which is only half of their actual size).

Set your `spinner-inline` css to:

```
.spinner-inline{
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
```

And they will no longer overlap.

*Alternatively, it looks like setting this does make the spinners spin on origin as well.